# Choose which javascript/jquery libraries to load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

My app has a very slow loading time when users navigate to the home screen. Also, when my students are trying to use my app from a school district computer, with its strict firewalls, they frequently encounter ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error screens. I suspect that one major contributor to these problems is that the head of each page is loading way too many javascript and jquery libraries.

Months ago, when I first began implementing jquery and javascript into my app, I vaguely recall that I was supposed to selectively include only the necessary jquery features in application.js. Now I no longer remember the vocabulary that I need to look up this concept. Below, I'll include the html file that is compiled by my app. As you can see, there are almost 130 lines of scripts being loaded. This can't be normal, can it?

Here is the html file as seen in Chrome's Page Inspector.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Miss Kohler | Mr. Z School </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/jquery-ui/theme.self-830c3407ba1359ea36eee978235be14de5b78dacfa658a31226fe4f2b0faa7e7.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/jquery-ui/core.self-e4bdefd3813c8a715955a6c65b9e730846dcae6a0576618563d635ff0b18a3ca.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/jquery-ui/accordion.self-aa0730fc025317fed4feff2aa5fc07cba5a545dfc5c913a2984ba6f8695b29fb.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/jquery-ui/autocomplete.self-f0b810a4a7bb8c90994675d7c5bfe636d615a5785cf81cae3340aa5e6adc55ca.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/jquery-ui/button.self-c459cf02498a2311af9ededbe220879035792a81f5f8478d47edd8f9aa202be2.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/jquery-ui/checkboxradio.self-98c7262aff3710f07beb8142dc6fb7c88ef0596dedb7909984e5554e06450760.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/jquery-ui/controlgroup.self-5f4cfb6eb047fc4a163c63848156a4bf2dc4daf33358aff3aa63fa10a31f9011.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/jquery-ui/datepicker.self-3047420a03ae2233615bf455c1e7804ce8804db93879fcdcd757f73ce60ebec1.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/jquery-ui/dialog.self-cfc405a38e0296def8d55cc92cac53d0a2006709b2376a36a31d2f31e5fa839d.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/jquery-ui/draggable.self-37c2539362d9d0af129d37fb409f6c33f35d75492c61c05a8dc4f278a0d9057f.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/jquery-ui/menu.self-5bc653bb1a86d1ac2565267f7c29a590fb1b07b9abc75d696d18408c376fa1e1.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/jquery-ui/progressbar.self-1b6f4c0b705f8fa475f566643777a7a62dc3bcad5e8d8c8b7a643226827a35f7.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/jquery-ui/resizable.self-664ac62d66e39e618f230faeba7e4745104a6217009c0f02a5ef78d00146c9b8.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/jquery-ui/selectable.self-19c99ff0e762c31563133c19f00eaea0c6901bc26757751c8eef675ef117a977.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/jquery-ui/selectmenu.self-4c64fa52068bb0ab5ab7beee995fb73714c5cfb571e1a9878ae67d4221ba62ad.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/jquery-ui/sortable.self-cfd0c3e3334e30aac7be47a8577778f43a41d737fd78981dca9f2ebc05351c31.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/jquery-ui/slider.self-4eeb158ab946298510cd1c33edbbb15be2310642f056555b156e27417fdd85bc.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/jquery-ui/spinner.self-7031500c1e002a164c88716bc7e947a35bf63ac016274357338097bf35cab77d.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/jquery-ui/tabs.self-d3e3dd1ce30228648f314c5c5bb8c40cb8aecdad4bbda8d1b1eb8eb496cda303.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/jquery-ui/tooltip.self-a7e58af2915ed216ce5a397dbe7db194a5c1d51e8876136cae3903d9ae41c6d9.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/jquery-ui/base.self-76599afe9b7687b8479ce5344363edbf948b417613a3beec7a7a74bacb0cc1c8.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/jquery-ui/all.self-131cc322272828d76a6354d061a4660293e55426159aa19231ad578926b73f4a.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/jquery-ui.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/consultancies.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/custom.self-0ce85a35dedf6ce78b22db5f1d250100bf62058221c10bf9ca7156ceb8aa38b3.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/label_objectives.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/labels.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/objective_seminars.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/objective_users.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/objectives.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/pictures.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/preconditions.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/questions.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/quizzes.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/ripostes.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/scaffolds.self-714f3a8b7051ae399d4f1653c6394ec9a188cb2a54639de6f3689b02b66067fc.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/seminars.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/sessions.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/students.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/teams.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/users.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application.self-d885a0a66bd595c10edb24f8879f94e334d88be0730c4d7c7a7b57c731c09037.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
  <script src="/assets/jquery.self-660adc51e0224b731d29f575a6f1ec167ba08ad06ed5deca4f1e8654c135bf4c.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.turbolinks.self-176b9819f30444d441e820bbccd3264fe57753aeafd54dec732b0dbc77129a2a.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/version.self-c8e3d1203da26ea7efdf83c1eabb3f0ba55cb68e463f5ccf0d77bd15ce6a8e61.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/data.self-2067c82e6fe39a9cba5623206a5dc28d5c60d26b95cd100855b78cacf72865b8.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/disable-selection.self-5675f71f2fbbc6857ea700ba843af748b50dbc0150cc87932a7d05ec016bb659.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/focusable.self-426e99e67d1f1bd4cb444fd878ee63a6de1f5d1d61451e43022c86214b9eec64.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/form.self-711978b53107be2d9ef1b7369beb151b229cefa8c1405a056d3c34262d5b477e.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/ie.self-163eb039dcb1e0c3471b7d91386eabb8753da6906e84824c019f9ff56bdb83a6.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/keycode.self-ad63cd20acf49dd333bbbc537454d7d475bd610eb5b88de0dca009f0c3d314b1.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/escape-selector.self-43e4d61501e4ffb1ecba387affbae1eb3e1c863ab0b0e71897851cddd246e50e.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/labels.self-c0448a3cb597a9a9429be814ab0e9ed2a14d85604555b4cff897adf3f0415f38.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/jquery-1-7.self-22c197e38fc01a29431530c4c5c7263e26d2b611994b1f9c5c8c900a97b4bc44.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/plugin.self-d8f576c8e073ca51f095505f47bd09d306b875404cd90afcbb6338287cfb0247.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/safe-active-element.self-a1f1a1a7dae3269ce03f6fffb2dcc9b4a7490f5d546c65d54417bec3be24b668.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/safe-blur.self-2cc24c46132d51c7724f6371154241b0a81c9bae5d5681d8f62b01ce46236726.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/scroll-parent.self-38e26a71a450a29fb63425e8f589a7046862f927eb0a1dbf6a6c44da05196d2e.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/tabbable.self-f3f62ceed772d3a325cebd6a03221f8a8cb02c6150f4feba738c6525a2953690.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/unique-id.self-66e85ac85cd0b6b8b1bb89369fc65f608f716869dc0930862a8d421a57a9580a.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/core.self-886760af898381620a8980841c646ae70e894b5292c3138e6dfd75b6904deffb.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect.self-776455da1682afff3a4974146aa96ca840597b879ed3797af0604063527443c6.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/form-reset-mixin.self-3a447942586b5719fdd7f1d1a3ac0da9e757a0eb8f4a7cb145f6deb820d2dc54.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/position.self-1b49c8c521e67a4a88bfdad6b4d944d33686d25009a0e40a1e170acdd7b6962a.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widget.self-fca20bcec06d192f97cffa6e734e24360e227237b8ae7d7e7e60754df7d5444f.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effects/effect-blind.self-2f8923f5c3073717dad35ac1f9bd4dbc13d2f9c8128f7dbea9819921338271f4.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effects/effect-bounce.self-ca3686abc7c667b5380422af36b618923c2fc8e901b3eb2ff627f1cdef60486a.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effects/effect-clip.self-9e606afd1b0d1679f42b1ce5c2ad29f242ed98a9b1a473a9ef8a8bf10df2afe4.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effects/effect-drop.self-481600061a28b5621b1d78187468e63f057665ce6af6401db851f9b79e345965.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effects/effect-explode.self-b5f68a634df4bc19111474eb15bcd99597dc19c721b33647fbb04f2bb6d52ca3.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effects/effect-fade.self-60febf4d2a1f6f013852a42da59c74d840f205715162a2b11e734fd4dd73a519.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effects/effect-fold.self-78adc6cc7f2d8dac25e8c82164ae61cc3160bb5280ed3d24dd96a576e37a6e46.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effects/effect-highlight.self-842a0db414abed8fbccb48908bd933b32c93c6b9d725160c85dc2bde708fa753.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effects/effect-size.self-2094878ac7ba38dcd4539cd4595fa4d6ed7182be8bb6f03785684a5e470a293d.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effects/effect-scale.self-88872e591cdbf30b3d09946e82e96e25bcd99b03857ead844a503301e6de71f3.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effects/effect-puff.self-be0ba8a98762bf10054deb4e8bdf92c44de0d570714624d16c396f1ffe3a82d6.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effects/effect-pulsate.self-bf83d1979be265f242fceb95cc3cfeca5467e4aab9cdea27ebb6f2e17bdaae2e.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effects/effect-shake.self-867270f4e72f7895d38b10fdf9a6ba20f22bee88ac4d79654a9227c14141e1ca.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effects/effect-slide.self-b59b0b36df7b3e5e4f4190ab51e5c212744d2b34d5ed14c96bfe9c8a3096c00b.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/effects/effect-transfer.self-5ab6d30ecb0b73e2b9a528f6d66c0732ba43a93a5326d88dae547f0c7c759e79.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widgets/accordion.self-267aabfe487e53fce0399a77f9030a87b9d8a409eb30c4c85c5637da9ac35429.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widgets/menu.self-0730fe713007bd93e6db569352a20ed92448299505ff6f525bc0dc6dd488254e.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widgets/autocomplete.self-6a89d7a43741ec810ef95de143a7c0297e2e4368ebecff64493ebb7a9ac3a524.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widgets/controlgroup.self-0b7409f97114a33de116bd5429e9df199cbdea3f276d8bd725c4c2c60f244711.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widgets/checkboxradio.self-60f68cb16012ef210c931076ada2d65d54a8c74a2dc71ce383af758460f8b686.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widgets/button.self-659b51f6fb5303f90ed8cf551509063770a50168a15795ba834b08f8bf2e0ce0.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widgets/datepicker.self-2af0dec09da99d687c31fc224e940687a4eb3694e7b38b0871bba475cad86120.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widgets/mouse.self-f0790a202dcf54fab051e71b042335d5346f9cceb0f645223c1dab93f349a04b.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widgets/draggable.self-42c3eda0b49f105628cea7580fe38c7ed77467cee384bb2c4e095a2bd0a172e6.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widgets/resizable.self-1a46c2f5b876918e02bf979080e56f57846590cd880721bca5058e84f7f60bae.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widgets/dialog.self-2bd687f9580c0be4213c50b4bb1211c28ceedb045eba954e63d40bfbb4d1affd.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widgets/droppable.self-4e3be0d7524dd1852e3b37ae00cd0c351c6178bcad39b17315cca941ddd44148.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widgets/progressbar.self-3bf965ce4e8ade2f07336ae5ffce7fe58897333238561761ffcb16f31af673fc.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widgets/selectable.self-a364da09c555890f5bb64704711594a88e94988edb285735bda59431a749226e.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widgets/selectmenu.self-43e0fc6b5fba037933a7d89a5b2a7127aa9c7494cc605c2dcd3146265e2d3d35.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widgets/slider.self-f166e8b345d6a2376ab8f43b05ab7629016706df83f2d96113cf5d8905c3d028.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widgets/sortable.self-6e5e1f07a29b5a89ec1d359363d2800904e3ae548a38ab2f8eded36746d1adbe.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widgets/spinner.self-2769386b6b06e175a13ccdcd6d2d0cd40c45cec19607bcb818cee0704c165557.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widgets/tabs.self-b7f60535e992224ca66c3f11dc943eba9ef42a9605241e27b9dba24c7efb287e.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/widgets/tooltip.self-50ae9488af573c99a78b60209bce5c7a4affc4e175fef523942acb163dd8deb8.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui.self-d4c1ae19d9b853ec1c8c83784fa979bbe4075a84932a080bbd7d7706240410e1.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.self-e87806d0cf4489aeb1bb7288016024e8de67fd18db693fe026fe3907581e53cd.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap.self-d0e973a52d36a01036265aeefaf2d1ae3499d2cb231a9be3bd846432daf231de.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.purr.self-b53f8f68f6b9035b1aff380084b6b0ffc6bab3f968accf488c78af31a759c717.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.autosize.self-208a4ea73c22b3517889027ffae7a076a0c5b4c38e4b595639979f10ada2ebe4.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/best_in_place.self-1230649fa74f159308492b42fc5bbf1ba4df1860c335c767e6dbfc17fb8b5cef.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/turbolinks.self-1d1fddf91adc38ac2045c51f0a3e05ca97d07d24d15a4dcbf705009106489e69.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/consultancies.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/label_objectives.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/labels.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/objective_seminars.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/objective_users.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/objectives.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/pictures.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/preconditions.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/questions.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/quizzes.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/ripostes.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/seminar_users.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/seminars.self-83aa821aa204b926aa28559cce64cf4849086480f2ad43ae513b83bfd7b10dca.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/sessions.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/students.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/teams.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/users.self-125cc80e97fc2de6f98127765ccbb4193c719ebf4f3e0c9ad1522fcda1772ee2.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.self-a1a74291c4c48f2f663a025ffa678498d6448b849a2d74c0ca25e39ee192c0a7.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
  <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="v84ZB1AFMpb2jT7aRKeZrIg+kezcbYLY3YczWQf95dOWtqv/JpEV7l2S3uMpvoL00m9tOCaSoTTAwWX/pB2JoQ==" />
   <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/r29/html5.min.js">
      </script>
 <![endif]-->

</head>
```

Here is my application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery.purr
//= require best_in_place
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Thank you in advance for any insight.

Comment: For starters why all the individual jQuery UI scripts on not load the whole library?

Comment: Use web pack or gulp. You have a lot of HTTP request.

Comment: you should- a) use a bundling tool like webpack. b) see if some of those scripts can be removed.

Comment: @charletti I don't want to load all the individual jQuery scripts. I would rather load the whole library. How do I do that?

Comment: @RaajNadar. I'm happy to use webpack if that's the best solution. But shouldn't there be a built-in way to minimize the loading from just the jquery gem and the jquery-ui gem. Without having to add another gem or service?

Comment: @awd. Do you know how I can try to remove some of those scripts?

Comment: A quick tip load the js files just before the closing body tag. So that the web page gets time to load the DOM elements.

Comment: @RaajNadar. This really does seem to help with performance. Is this really best-practice? All of the tutorials I learned from instructed me to load the javascript in the head.

Comment: Scripts should never be run before the elements are loaded. Eg- lets say you have click event attached to a button if you load the scripts before the element is loaded in the DOM. The script wont find the button because the page was not loaded completely. This happens to users with slow internet. And even performance will be low because you have a lot of http request to the same place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're most likely seeing all of those individual scripts because you're running your server in *development* mode. According to the [Asset Pipeline Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html),

> In development mode, assets are served as separate files in the order they are specified in the manifest file.

This works fine, when you're running the server on your localhost for your own use - but it's not good if you've got lots of users trying to connect and request all of those individual files.

For your public-facing website, you'll want to be sure that you're running in *production* mode, not *development*.  In production mode, your javascripts and stylesheets should be precompiled into a single javascript file and a single css file.  You can precompile your assets by running the following command:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bin/rails assets:precompile
```

Then, if you start your server in production mode, you shouldn't see the huge list of separate assets in your `<head>`.

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails server
```

Comment: You're right. In my live site, the head is very reasonable. So do you think that I've probably done all I can do in this area to improve performance on my site?

Comment: The other thing you can do would be to _only_ load those jquery-ui components that you're actually using on your site.  This would reduce the size of the compiled application.js file, which can't hurt!  There's instructions on the [jquery-ui-rails README](https://github.com/jquery-ui-rails/jquery-ui-rails) for which components are available to load separately.

Comment: I think this is actually what I was trying to ask in the first place. I just wasn't sure how to ask it correctly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I won't say this is a proper answer to your question but you should check this question that I created in the past that is somewhat similar to your problem.

[Efficiency when loading JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38331410/efficiency-when-loading-javascript)

Lesser the files that are imported faster the page loads.